# What kind of structure is "think us going"?

Tags: grammar

What grammatical rule does the following structure in bold refer to?

> "I don't **think us going** to visit this Caesare Aldanto fellow is a good idea."
>
> From "The Shadow of the Lion"

Comment: "I don't think [that] _us going to visit CA_ is a good idea"

Comment: @KateBunting - But why is an object pronoun used that way? Shouldn't it be like "I don't think we should go to visit CA"?

Comment: Well, of course that would be another way of saying it, but that doesn't mean that this way is wrong, though it's informal, colloquial speech. Presumably they have been making plans for the visit before someone suggests that it isn't a good idea.

Comment: @KateBunting - Is this structure based on a specific grammatical rule? I'd like to find other examples.

Comment: Actually, the correct version would be 'I don't think _our_ going to visit him would be a good idea'. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner